# Master user of AWS RDS doesn't have privileges for various actions

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created an oracle RDS in AWS, and then tried to do several actions with the master user which is created initially.

It looks like this master user does not have privileges to perform various actions.

```
     ORA-31685: Object type SYSTEM_GRANT:"testuser" failed due to insufficient privileges. Failing sql is:
     GRANT CREATE ANY DIRECTORY TO "testuser"
     ORA-31685: Object type SYSTEM_GRANT:"testuser" failed due to insufficient privileges. Failing sql is:
     GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO "testuser"
```

How can I give all privileges to the master user of the RDS, so master user can perform above actions without any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the Oracle RDS is a managed service, some privilleges are not available

In particular

> The following privileges are not available for the DBA role on an
>   Amazon RDS DB instance using the Oracle engine:
>
> Alter database
>
> Alter system
>
> Create any directory
>
> Drop any directory
>
> Grant any privilege
>
> Grant any role

see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Oracle.html#Oracle.Concepts.RestrictedDBAPrivileges